# React: Using different layouts for different routes

Tags: reactjs

I am encountering a somewhat odd issue try to split my components into using two different layouts. I have 2 layouts: `PublicLayout` and `Layout` where my `App.js` has my routes defined as such:

```
render() {
    return (
      <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <Layout>
          <Route path="/articles" component={ArticlesIndex} exact={true} />
          <Route
             path="/articles/create"
             component={ArticlesCreate}
             exact={true}
          />
          <Route
            path="/articles/edit/:id"
            component={ArticlesEdit}
            exact={true}
          />
        </Layout>
        <PublicLayout>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} exact={true} />
          <Route 
          path="/articles/view/:id"
          component={ArticlesView}
          exact={true}
          />
        </PublicLayout>
      </ApolloProvider>
     );
   }
```

Here is what `Layout` looks like:

```
<div className="container">
    <Grid fluid>
      <Row>
        <Col sm={12}>
          {this.props.children}
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Grid>
  </div>
```

All of my routes/components that are inside the `PublicLayout` tag render and operate as expected. However, all of my routes/components which use my `Layout` component are rendered as expected but then have the `PublicLayout` rendered below them. I'm guessing  `PublicLayout` is being included on these pages since it appears with no qualifying conditions after the `Layout` section. How can I overcome this and only render the `PublicLayout` on the routes which it includes?

All help is appreciated.

UPDATE: I've solved my issue by using the following which allowed me to define arbitrarily, on a per-route basis which layout each route gets:

```
function renderWithLayout(Component, Layout, props) {
  return <Layout><Component {...props}/></Layout>
}


export default class App extends Component {
  displayName = App.name;

  render() {
    return (
      <ApolloProvider client={client}>
          <Route 
            path="/articles" 
            render={(props) => renderWithLayout(ArticlesIndex, Layout, props)} 
            exact={true} 
            />
          <Route
             path="/articles/create"
             render={(props) => renderWithLayout(ArticlesCreate, Layout, props)}
             exact={true}
          />
          <Route
            path="/articles/edit/:id"
            render={(props) => renderWithLayout(ArticlesEdit, Layout, props)}
            exact={true}
          />
          <Route 
            path="/" 
            render={(props) => renderWithLayout(Home, PublicLayout, props)} 
            exact={true} 
            />
          <Route 
              path="/articles/view/:id"
              render={(props) => renderWithLayout(ArticlesView, PublicLayout, props)}
              exact={true}
              />
      </ApolloProvider>
     );
   }
}
```

Comment: Was I able to answer your question properly?

Comment: @Mark the condition is the route that's being visited. Im not sure how i can assign a variable to that

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional rendering.  Let's pretend `loggedIn` is what you use to keep track of if a user has been authenticated or not.

```
render() {
    return {
      <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        { loggedIn ? (
        <Layout>
          <Route path="/articles" component={ArticlesIndex} exact={true} />
          <Route
             path="/articles/create"
             component={ArticlesCreate}
             exact={true}
          />
          <Route
            path="/articles/edit/:id"
            component={ArticlesEdit}
            exact={true}
          />
        </Layout>
        ) : (
        <PublicLayout>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} exact={true} />
          <Route 
          path="/articles/view/:id"
          component={ArticlesView}
          exact={true}
          />
        </PublicLayout>
       )}
      </ApolloProvider>
     );
   }
```

For other examples and solutions https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: I don't have a condition to switch off of. My condition is the route itself and which route gets what layout can be considered an arbitrary choice.

Comment: I guess I don't follow what you are trying to do.

Comment: Have you looked into React Router's ```match``` object? https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/match
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/match.md

Comment: see my update- I've found a way to do what I was looking for.

Comment: Great.  I still don't understand what you are trying to accomplish with this.  There is also ```Switch``` which may have helped as well.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing any important detail here, it looks like react is doing exactly what your render function is telling it to do. There is no conditional rendering there, so you're always going to have Layout and PublicLayout.

Solve it by adding a conditional around them. You could simply extract into two different functions and render one or the other based on whatever condition you'd like to drive that output.

Comment: So exactly like my answer?

Comment: I guess @Mark just gave a beautiful example of what I was trying to say.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I believe we had the same thought, you just happen to be faster than me and more detailed - actually giving the solution :D

Comment: I have great luck with getting the right answer and having no one ever upvoting it or straight up ignoring it. =)

Comment: I feel ya. There's something very selfish about people not upvoting when they believe they could've answered. I up voted your question because it actually helps much more than mine does.